# How to display an error message on HTML page when the login credentials are wrong? (cgi-bin)

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication, cgi

I am making a simple WIFI splash page now. If the credentials are correct, it will open a URL. However, I don't know how to handle the wrong login credentials. (It only refreshes the page when submitting with the wrong username and password.)

**Here is my html code:**

```
<form method=POST action="https://securelogin.*******.com/cgi-bin/login">
  <div class="row">
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input name=user class="u-full-width" type="text">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input name=password class="u-full-width" type="password">
      <input name=cmd value="authenticate" type="hidden">
      <input name=url value="http://www.google.com/" type="hidden">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="Login" value="I Agree">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Expected behavior:** If the credential is wrong, show an error message somewhere in the form.

**Issues:** I don't know where to add what code to trigger the error message when the credential is wrong.

I have done some research. It seems like people usually handle it by using **php/js**. I am not sure if that's what I should do, because I don't know how the action links in my code works, especially the **"cgi-bin"** part. The only thing I know is it will be a  RADIUS call to the server to verify the credentials. The action link cannot be changed.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: _cgi-bin_ is usually Perl scripts if I'm not mistaken. PHP has nothing to do with that. You need your Perl script to return an error and let your website check if that error exists and display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Javascript using the JQuery library. Instead of your form being submitted as a POST request, the Javascript will handle the POST request and get the data from your login page.

You would need $.post() to send the POST request, and $.toggle() to show or hide an error message element. You could even set an error message from your post page to a Javascript variable in your page. The library is very simple and easy to implement.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Tell me, did you actually put some time in reading the question? Or did you just read the title and gave some kind of random answer?